# Option pricing: Relationship between Theta and early exercise

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance

I am confused about the following:

For a European put option, the parameter $\Theta$ is given by
$$ \Theta= \frac{d V}{dt} =  -\frac{SN'(d_1) \sigma}{2 \sqrt{T-t}} + rK e^{-r(T-t)}N(-d_2).$$

My textbook claims the following:

> For deep-in-the-money European puts, $S<<K$. Hence, $d_1, d_2 \approx - \infty$, which implies that $N'(d_1) \approx 0$ and $N(-d_2) \approx 1$. Hence, $\Theta >0$.  This shows **that it can be optimal to exercise a deep-in-the-money American put before maturity.**

I have two questions regarding this statement:

1. I have a deep confusion. $\Theta$ measures the rate of change of $V$ with respect to $t$ by its definition. Hence, a positive value of $\Theta$ should imply that the put option increases in value over time. This means that we should wait further for the future increase in the value of the option and therefore **wait and not exercise at the moment**.
2. The formula of $\Theta$ comes from the Black-Scholes formula of $V$, which is only valid for **European** options, from what I know.  Therefore, I am puzzled about the conclusion regarding the American counterpart in my textbook.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, we can use this: $Put^\text{Amer}_t(T,K) \geq Put_t(T,K)$?

Comment: @Sesame OK, this makes sense. Any ideas about my first question? I still think we should wait instead of exercising the option....

Comment: From my memory, we can use the "Early exercise premium" argument.  Basically show that  $Put^\text{Amer}_t(T,K) \leq Put_t(T,K) + K(1-e^{-r(T-t)})$.